# How to convert std::string to LPCSTR?

Tags: c++, windows, string

How can I convert a `std::string` to `LPCSTR`? Also, how can I convert a `std::string` to `LPWSTR`?

I am totally confused with these `LPCSTR` `LPSTR` `LPWSTR` and `LPCWSTR`.

Are `LPWSTR` and `LPCWSTR` the same?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`str.c_str()` gives you a `const char *`, which is an `LPCSTR` (Long Pointer to Constant STRing) -- means that it's a pointer to a `0` terminated string of characters.  `W` means wide string (composed of `wchar_t` instead of `char`).

Comment: Minor picky point: on x64 LPCSTR would be a 64-bit pointer to a (constant) null-terminated string.

Answer (score 178):

Call `c_str()` to get a `const char *` (`LPCSTR`) from a `std::string`.

It's all in the name:

`LPSTR` - (long) pointer to string - `char *`

`LPCSTR` - (long) pointer to constant string - `const char *`

`LPWSTR` - (long) pointer to Unicode (wide) string - `wchar_t *`

`LPCWSTR` - (long) pointer to constant Unicode (wide) string - `const wchar_t *`

`LPTSTR` - (long) pointer to TCHAR (Unicode if UNICODE is defined, ANSI if not) string - `TCHAR *`

`LPCTSTR` - (long) pointer to constant TCHAR string - `const TCHAR *`

You can ignore the L (long) part of the names -- it's a holdover from 16-bit Windows.

Answer (score 35):

These are Microsoft defined typedefs which correspond to:

LPCSTR: pointer to null terminated const string of `char`

LPSTR: pointer to null terminated char string of `char` (often a buffer is passed and used as an 'output' param)

LPCWSTR: pointer to null terminated string of const `wchar_t`

LPWSTR: pointer to null terminated string of `wchar_t` (often a buffer is passed and used as an 'output' param)

To "convert" a `std::string` to a LPCSTR depends on the exact context but usually calling `.c_str()` is sufficient.

This works.

```
void TakesString(LPCSTR param);

void f(const std::string& param)
{
    TakesString(param.c_str());
}
```

Note that you shouldn't attempt to do something like this.

```
LPCSTR GetString()
{
    std::string tmp("temporary");
    return tmp.c_str();
}
```

The buffer returned by `.c_str()` is owned by the `std::string` instance and will only be valid until the string is next modified or destroyed.

To convert a `std::string` to a `LPWSTR` is more complicated. Wanting an `LPWSTR` implies that you need a modifiable buffer and you also need to be sure that you understand what *character encoding* the `std::string` is using. If the `std::string` contains a string using the system default encoding (assuming windows, here), then you can find the length of the required wide character buffer and perform the transcoding using `MultiByteToWideChar` (a Win32 API function).

e.g.

```
void f(const std:string& instr)
{
    // Assumes std::string is encoded in the current Windows ANSI codepage
    int bufferlen = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, instr.c_str(), instr.size(), NULL, 0);

    if (bufferlen == 0)
    {
        // Something went wrong. Perhaps, check GetLastError() and log.
        return;
    }

    // Allocate new LPWSTR - must deallocate it later
    LPWSTR widestr = new WCHAR[bufferlen + 1];

    ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, instr.c_str(), instr.size(), widestr, bufferlen);

    // Ensure wide string is null terminated
    widestr[bufferlen] = 0;

    // Do something with widestr

    delete[] widestr;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Using `LPWSTR` you could change contents of string where it points to. Using `LPCWSTR` you couldn't change contents of string where it points to.

```
std::string s = SOME_STRING;
// get temporary LPSTR (not really safe)
LPSTR pst = &s[0];
// get temporary LPCSTR (pretty safe)
LPCSTR pcstr = s.c_str();
// convert to std::wstring
std::wstring ws; 
ws.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );
// get temporary LPWSTR (not really safe)
LPWSTR pwst = &ws[0];
// get temporary LPCWSTR (pretty safe)
LPCWSTR pcwstr = ws.c_str();
```

`LPWSTR` is just a pointer to original string. You shouldn't return it from function using the sample above. To get not temporary `LPWSTR` you should made a copy of original string on the heap. Check the sample below:

```
LPWSTR ConvertToLPWSTR( const std::string& s )
{
  LPWSTR ws = new wchar_t[s.size()+1]; // +1 for zero at the end
  copy( s.begin(), s.end(), ws );
  ws[s.size()] = 0; // zero at the end
  return ws;
}

void f()
{
  std::string s = SOME_STRING;
  LPWSTR ws = ConvertToLPWSTR( s );

  // some actions

  delete[] ws; // caller responsible for deletion
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Converting is simple:

```
std::string myString;

LPCSTR lpMyString = myString.c_str();
```

One thing to be careful of here is that c_str does not return a copy of myString, but just a pointer to the character string that std::string wraps. If you want/need a copy you'll need to make one yourself using strcpy.

Answer (score 5):

The `MultiByteToWideChar` answer that Charles Bailey gave is the correct one. Because `LPCWSTR` is just a typedef for `const WCHAR*`, `widestr` in the example code there can be used wherever a `LPWSTR` is expected or where a `LPCWSTR` is expected.

One minor tweak would be to use `std::vector<WCHAR>` instead of a manually managed array:

```
// using vector, buffer is deallocated when function ends
std::vector<WCHAR> widestr(bufferlen + 1);

::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, instr.c_str(), instr.size(), &widestr[0], bufferlen);

// Ensure wide string is null terminated
widestr[bufferlen] = 0;

// no need to delete; handled by vector
```

Also, if you need to work with wide strings to start with, you can use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`. If you want to work with the Windows `TCHAR` type, you can use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`. Converting from `std::wstring` to `LPCWSTR` or from `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` to `LPCTSTR` is just a matter of calling `c_str`. It's when you're changing between ANSI and UTF-16 characters that `MultiByteToWideChar` (and its inverse `WideCharToMultiByte`) comes into the picture.

Answer (score 3):

The conversion is simple:

```
std::string str;
LPCSTR lpcstr = str.c_str();
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to convert a `std::string` to a `LPWSTR` is in my opinion:

1. Convert the `std::string` to a `std::vector<wchar_t>`
2. Take the address of the first `wchar_t` in the vector.

`std::vector<wchar_t>` has a templated ctor which will take two iterators, such as the `std::string.begin()` and `.end()` iterators. This will convert each char to a `wchar_t`, though. That's only valid if the `std::string` contains ASCII or Latin-1, due to the way Unicode values resemble Latin-1 values. If it contains CP1252 or characters from any other encoding, it's more complicated. You'll then need to convert the characters.

Comment: Why not use `std::wstring`?

Comment: @Timmmm: C++11 tightened the specification as implementations didn't take advantage of the old rules, today that would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string myString("SomeValue");
LPSTR lpSTR = const_cast<char*>(myString.c_str());
```

*myString* is the input string and *lpSTR* is it's **LPSTR** equivalent.