# C++ Winapi. Read first line from a file, displaying in a textbox

Tags: c++, winapi, fstream

I have recently begun to experiment with winapi in C++. Coming along nicely so far.

I do however having a problem with finding a way to read the first line of a file, and displaying it in a textbox.

After some google searching it seems that some people suggest using winapis functions for this, while other say that using fstream is simpler. I did go the fstream way but i run in to some trouble, probably nothing very difficult but, i cannot find an answer for it!

this is my code:

```
string line;
ifstream filen ("tid.txt");
if (filen.is_open())
   {

   getline (filen,line);
   cout << line << endl;
   filen.close();
   }

   SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT, line);
```

This give me this problem from the compiler:

```
Cannot convert `std::string' to `const CHAR*'
```

Need somekind of conversion here, but dont know what.

What do you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert std::string to LPCSTR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT, line.c_str());
```

Comment: or try this SetDlgItemTextA(hwnd, IDC_MAIN_EDIT, line.c_str());

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your fast answer! It sure did work. Could you explain the difference in this? Just so i understand :)

Comment: The c_str() method returns a constant pointer to the array which contains the zero-terminated sequence of characters. That is, you get the C-string wrapped by the std::string object.

Comment: @DanielSvensson If you are satisfied, would you please consider accepting my answer?