# How to retrieve the specific element from an array of std::strings as a LPCSTR?

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc, stdstring, lpcstr

In C++,
I've got a string array variable called:

```
...
/* set the variable */
string fileRows[500];
...
/* fill the array with a file rows */
while ( getline(infile,sIn ) )
{
    fileRows[i] = sIn;
    i++;
}
```

and an object which has this:

```
string Data::fileName(){
    return (fileRows);
}
```

I would like to make a function which return an array, and after that i would like to call it something like this:

```
Data name(hwnd);
MessageBox(hwnd, name.fileName(), "About", MB_OK);
```

But i get this error:

> cannot convert 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string*}' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '2' to 'int MessageBoxA(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT)'

If i would like to show the 5. element of the array, how to convert it?

Comment: `MessageBox(hwnd, name.fileName().c_str(), "About", MB_OK);`?

Comment: what's the declaration for MessageBoxA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fileRows is an array of 500 elements. If you want to return the array so that you can later access the n-th element, you should return the pointer to the beginning of the array. For example:

```
string* Data::fileName(){
        return fileRows;
}
```

Although it is probably better to use:

```
const string& Data::getFileName(size_t index){
        return fileRows[index];
}
```

Using the first method, you can access the n-th element using:

```
data.filename()[n];
```

So, if you want to access the 5th element of the array you should use:

```
data.filename()[4];
```

On the other hand, the function MessageBox needs a const char *. So you must call the c_str() method to get the pointer:

```
Data name(hwnd);
MessageBox(hwnd, name.fileName()[4].c_str(), "About", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem! :-)
Thank you!

Comment: -1 `fileName[5]` is not 5th element.

Comment: @LihO You are right, but I didn't say it was. Anyway, I will update the answer to clarify.

Comment: Right, Milla Jovovich the 5th element.

Answer (score 5):

`LPCSTR` is nothing else but an alias for `const char*`. The problem is that the `Data::fileName()` returns a [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) object and there's no implicit conversion to `const char*`.

To retrieve a string from the `std::string` in form of `const char*`, use [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) method , :

```
MessageBox(hwnd, name.fileName().c_str(), "About", MB_OK);
```

---

Also note that you have created an array of `std::string` objects:

```
string fileRows[500];
```

but in the `Data::fileName()` you're trying to return it as a single `std::string` object:

```
string Data::fileName() {
    return fileRows;
}
```

I recommend you to use `std::vector` instead of C-style array though.

> *If i would like to show the 5. element of the array, how to convert it?*

No matter whether you will use `std::vector` or keep using an array, it will look like this:

```
std::string Data::fileName() {
    return fileRows[4];
}
```

Comment: `LPCSTR` is `char const*`. :-]

Comment: I got this error:
error: could not convert '(std::string*)(&((Data*)this)->Data::fileRows)' from 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'

Comment: Do you know how to convert this error, If I would like to show the 5. element of the array?

Comment: @David: There's another error that I overlooked before. Check my answer now :)

Comment: yes i know because i tried several ways to return a string array.
I tried with:
string* Data::fileName()...
<vector><string> Data::fileName()..
but none of them worked, beacause i dont know how to display an array element in the messagebox..

Comment: @David: `std::vector<std::string> fileRows` will allow you to treat `fileRows` almost in the same way as an array, but it will be flexible in size. I also answered your last question, check my answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

[std::string::c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) will give you a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) or `LPCSTR`

Answer (score 0):

use `std:string`'s function `c_str()` ... take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr)