# Why are so many string types in C++?

Tags: c++, c, string, c++-cli

I like C, I have a C book called Full and Full C and 2 C++, I find these languages fantastic because of their incredible power and performance, but I have to end many of my projects because of these various types.

I say to have `std::string`, `LPCSTR`, `System::String`, `TCHAR []`, `char s [] = "ss"`, `char * s`?

This causes tremendous headaches mainly in GUI applications, WinAPI has the problem of `LPCSTR` not being compatible with char or `std::string`, and now in CLR applications if it has `System::String` that gives a lot of headache to convert to `std::String` or `char * s` or even `char s []`.

Why don’t C/C++ have its string type unique like `String` in Java?

Comment: C only has (null-terminated) `char` arrays and string literals, no `string` type. And C++ provides some string classes (the most important being `std::string`) as part of its standard library, `LPCSTR` and `System::String` are not part of the language standard

Comment: The unique string types as in Java are `std::string` in C++ and `char[]` with an ending `'\0'` in C. Other types than this are either typedefs, structs or own classes and that's not the fault of C or C++.

Comment: some of them are strings in the C++ understanding some are tables zero terminated values which are called in the C strings

Comment: Actually, ``LPCSTR`` is just a ``char *``, as it's also pointed out in the microsoft winapi doc. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr

Comment: Use `std::string` - *that* is the accepted C++ string type. Even though legacy C strings are available, they're a horror to use. All the others are non-standard.

Comment: "_I would like C / C ++ to have its String type unique with String in java._" So why are you comparing 3 **different** languages, and asking why they have different string types, while Java is just a single language? C has `char*`/`char[]` (null-terminated array of characters). C++ has `std::string`, and C++/CLI (yet another language!), has `System::String`. `LPCTSTR` from WinApi is just a typedef to `TCHAR const *`, where TCHAR is either `char`, or `wchar_t`, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not. You can see why it might not be compatible with `std::string`.

Comment: You forgot BSTR, bstr_t, CComBSTR and CString etc.. As other people said these are all Windows strings. We use std::string in 95% of the code; rest when needed.

Comment: By the way, if you really wanted to you could also create your own `String` class in Java (there's really no point to it, but it is possible)

Comment: If you ask for C++ string types, why do you add C language tag? Please don't spam with unrelated tags.

Comment: C++ has single string type - `std::string`. The rest are not strings - it's "array of chars", so Java equivalent would be `char[]` or `byte[]`. BTW. as we speak of duplication, Java has `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer` (BTW. do you know the difference between the two? ;D)...

Comment: Three of those "string" types are Microsoft-isms. Microsoft's software is typically over-designed and bloated.

Comment: _“I have to end many of my projects because of these various types.”_ No reason for that! These types can be converted. For example, I use `char*`, `std::string`, `std::vector<unsigned char>`, `QByteArray` and `QString` in different classes of a single program and convert them when needed without any hassle.

Comment: As Java came later, the question should be "Why does  Java  have a  unique string type, unlike C/C++"

Comment: Windows API is older than C++

Comment: Is WinAPI not as useful as the new gui libs nowadays? There are Qt and wx but both are many similar to native api, such as Qt which is used by autodesk, adobe, allegorithmic among other famous companies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no "many types of string in c++". Canonically there is one template [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which is basically a container specialized for strings of different character types.

`std::string` is a convenience typedef onto `std::basic_string<char>`. There are more such typedefs for different underlying character types.

AFAIK, standard c has also only one officially recognized string standard. It's ANSI-string i.e. a null terminated array of `char`.

All other you mention are either equivalent of this (e.g. `LPCSTR` is a long pointer to a constant string i.e. `const char*`), or some non-standard extensions written by library providers.

Your question is like asking why there are so many GUI libraries. Because there is no standard way to do this, or standard way is lacking in some way, and it was a design decision to provide and support own equivalent type.

Bottom line is, that on the library level, or language level, it's a design decision between different trade-offs. Simplicity, performance, character support, etc. etc. In general, [storing text is hard](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2017/05/unicode-is-hard/).

Comment: There is no such thing as "ansi string" in C. There are many different kinds of strings in C including wide strings, char16_t strings and char32_t strings.

Comment: Could you point me to a in the C standard that would define any string so I can supplement my answer? I have tried searching [a draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for `char32_t` and found nothing. I was sure null terminated strings were standardized, but I might be wrong. I am not really a C expert.

Comment: @luk32: [C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 7.1.1.

Comment: @luk32 wrong version. C11 final draft, aka [n1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5)

Answer (score 4):

Well, first we must answer the question: **What is a string?**

The C-standard defines it as a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.<sup>1</sup>
It also mentions varieties using `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, or `char32_t` instead of `char`.
It also provides many functions for string-manipulation, and string-literals for notational convenience.

So, a sequence of characters can be a string, a `char[]` might hold a string, and a `char*` might point to one.
`LPCSTR` is a windows typedef for `const char*` with the added semantics that it should point to a string or be `NULL`.
`TCHAR` is one of a number of preprocessor-defines used for transitioning windows code from `char` to `wchar_t`. Depending on what `TCHAR` is, a `TCHAR[]` might be able to hold a string, or a wide-string.

---

C++ mixes up things a bit because it adds a data-type for handling strings. To reduce ambiguity, *string* is only used for the abstract concept, you have to rely on the context to disambiguate or be more explicit.

So the C *string* corresponds with the C++ *null-terminated-byte-string*, or *NTBS*.<sup>2</sup>
Yes, C++ also knows their wide varieties.
And C++ incorporates the C functions and adds some more.
In addition, C++ has `std::basic_string<>` for storing all kinds of counted strings, and some convenience-typedefs like `std::string`.

---

And now we get to the third language yet, namely C++/CLI.
Which incorporates all I spoke above from C++, and adds the CLI type `System::String` into the mix.
`System::String` is an immutable UTF-16 counted-string.

---

Now to answer the question why C++ does not define one single concrete type to be a string can be answered:

There are different types of string in C++ for interoperability, history, efficiency and convenience. Always use the right tool for the job.
Java and .Net do the same with byte-arrays, char-arrays, string-builders and the like.

---

Reference 1: C11 final draft, definition of string:

> #### 7. Library
>
> #### 7.1 Introduction
>
> #### 7.1.1 Deﬁnitions of terms
>
> 1 A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the ﬁrst null character. The term *multibyte string* is sometimes used instead to emphasize special processing given to multibyte characters contained in the string or to avoid confusion with a wide string. A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character. The *length of a string* is the number of bytes preceding the null character and the *value of a string* is the sequence of the values of the contained characters, in order.

Reference 2: C++1z draft n4659 NTBS:

> #### 20.4.2.1.5.1 Byte strings `[byte.strings]`
>
> 1 A *null-terminated byte string*, or *NTBS*, is a character sequence whose highest-addressed element with deﬁned content has the value zero (the *terminating null character*); no other element in the sequence has the value zero.163
>   2 The *length* of an *NTBS* is the number of elements that precede the terminating null character. An *empty* ntbs has a length of zero.
>   3 The *value* of an *NTBS* is the sequence of values of the elements up to and including the terminating null character.
>   4 A *static* *NTBS* is an *NTBS* with static storage duration.164

Answer (score 0):

Each string type has his own target, the `std::string` is for standard library and this is the most common.

As you say C++ has power and performance and these strings allow more flexibility. `Char[]` and `char*` you can use for a more generic use of string.