# How to convert wstring to LPWSTR array? (C++)

Tags: c++

I am having a wstring and I need to convert the string to LPWSTR array

```
wstring pathStr = L"C:/abc/xyz/example.txt";
LPWSTR path[260];
```

I need to assign the wstring variable "pathStr" to LPWSTR array.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert std::string to LPCSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr)

Comment: Do you need to copy it, or do you just need to pass a const pointer? If the latter, you can just use `pathStr.c_str()`

Comment: Doen't `LPWSTR path[260];` create an array of 260 pointers to strings? There is probably a `WCHAR` or similar to declare an array of characters.

Comment: What do you want your `path` to contain? It's an array of 260 pointers. What they are supposed to point to?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius types.

Comment: @n.m. Good point. I, somehow, read it as `WCHAR path[260]` :/

Comment: Change to WCHAR[], use wcscpy_s() to copy.