# cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string PNGFilePath, WEBPFilePath;
    int number, c;
    char title[256];

    cout << "Enter a Number: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Title: ";
    cin.getline(title, 256, ';');

    cout << "Enter PNG directory: ";
    cin >> PNGFilePath;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter WEBP directory: ";
    cin >> WEBPFilePath;
    cout << endl;

    std::string OldPNGFolder = std::string(PNGFilePath + "\\");
    c = 1;

    while (title[c] != '\0') {
        OldPNGFolder += title[c];
        c++;
    }

    std::string NewPNGFolder = std::string(PNGFilePath + "\\[");
    c = 1;
    NewPNGFolder += to_string(number);
    NewPNGFolder += "]";
    while (title[c] != '\0') {
        NewPNGFolder += title[c];
        c++;
    }

    MoveFile(OldPNGFolder, NewPNGFolder);
}
```

I tried adding "(OldPNGFolder.c_str()" and it still shows the same error message, also tried system(OldPNGFolder.c_str()); and still the same message.

Adding "LPCTSTR" shows the error "error: expected primary-expression before 'OldPNGFolder'
MoveFile(LPCTSTR OldPNGFolder, NewPNGFolder);"

Is there a way to fix this???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert std::string to LPCSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200188/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcstr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use Visual Studio?
If your project's `Character Set` is `Use Unicode Character Set` in the Project's Property window, MoveFile means that MoveFileW.
It's parameter type is LPCTSTR, that is const wchar_t *, not the const char *.
Your error is not in converting from string to const char *, just in parameter type error in MoveFile.

You can fix this by use MoveFileA, `MoveFileA(OldPNGFolder.c_str(), NewPNGFolder.c_str());` or by convert string to wstring or LPCWSTR as below.

```
wstring a2w(std::string & string_a)
{
    int length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, string_a.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);

    wchar_t* temp = new wchar_t[length];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, string_a.c_str(), -1, temp, length);

    wstring string_w = temp;
    delete[] temp;
    return string_w;
}

int main() {
    ...
    MoveFile(a2w(OldPNGFolder).c_str(), a2w(NewPNGFolder).c_str());
}
```